# Xcode TableViewCell push to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am creating an app where a table list of meals are displayed, and when you click on one it displays the meal in further detail.

When I run it it displays the meal on the table, but when I click on the meal it just gives the meal template,

[image: This is a picture of the storyboard]
Here is the code I'm using for my TableViewController to display items

```
private func loadSampleMeals() {

        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "Sprite")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "HotCheetos")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "Nachos")

        guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Sprite", price: "$1.50", photo: photo1, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 129", description: "Description: A refreshing lemon-lime soda") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
        }

        guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Hot Cheetos", price: "$1.50", photo: photo2, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 160", description: "Description: A spicy version of original cheetos") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Nachos", price: "$1.50", photo: photo3, rating: 0, calories: "Calories: 436", description: "Description: Tortilla chips with a side of smooth nacho cheese") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
    }


      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
            case "ShowDetail":
            guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }

            guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
            }

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }

            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
        }
    }
```

In the code, the guard statements should cause it to display the item data in the ViewController, but I get the default error at the bottom

Comment: did you pass data while change tableview controller to details controller ?

Comment: Can you show some code with your tableView method that will give us idea what you are doing

Comment: remove the top navigation controller... in app there should be only 1 navigation controllers...

Comment: post code that you are using to go to details... are you passing object to details or not?

Comment: Are you sure that your segue identifier is `ShowDetail`? Check once in storyboard and confirm here

Comment: Nirav D identifier wasn't ShowDetail whoops. Thanks for catching that mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the meal object on `didSelectRowAt`, for example you have an array of meals to generate the cells and theres only one section

```
var meals: [Meal] 

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return meals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
    let mealDetailsVC = MealDetailsViewController()
    mealDetailsVC.meal = selectedMeal

    navigationController?.pushViewController(mealDetailsVC, animated: true)
}
```